# Using CKEditor.d.ts typescript definition file in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have a project in angular 2 and i want to use CKEditor typescript definition from DefinitelyTyped Repo

> https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/ckeditor/ckeditor.d.ts

Problem is I am getting error `Evaluating http://localhost:3000/typings/ckeditor/ckeditor.d.ts` Here is my code for including the ckeditor file.

```
import {CoursesService} from "../../../services/courses"
/// <reference path="../../../../typings/ckeditor/ckeditor.d.ts" />

import {CKEDITOR} from "../../../../typings/ckeditor/ckeditor.d.ts"
export class CreateCourseComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit(){
        CKEDITOR.replace('text_area');
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this is NOT a duplicate of that question. That question is about how to use CKEDITOR. This one is about how to use the DefinitelyTyped type definitions for CKEDITOR. They are complementary.

Comment: And here's the answer to this question:
(1) Run `npm install -D @types/ckeditor`
(2) Add this to the very top of the typescript file where you'll access the CKEDITOR global (must be 1st line, or just after other triple-slash directives): `///<reference types="ckeditor" />`

Answer (score 0):

Definition file is not module, its compile time only, so remove this line:

```
import {CKEDITOR} from "../../../../typings/ckeditor/ckeditor.d.ts"
```

And import CKEditor using script tag.

Comment: removing this line doesnot solves this problem, it generates error `CKEditor is not defined`